# How to Find the sum for count(*) column which is came from another union result query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working in some query that should give the sum for count(*) column ,

my query :

```
SELECT sap_sys_id,
  stock_id,
  form,
  COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_doc
WHERE stock_id=
  (SELECT Q1_stock_id-1 FROM tbl_id_virtualpool
  )
AND spool_name NOT LIKE '%MXC%'
GROUP BY sap_sys_id,
  stock_id,
  form
UNION ALL
SELECT sap_sys_id,
  stock_id,
  form,
  COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_document_log
WHERE stock_id=
  (SELECT Q2_stock_id-1 FROM tbl_id_virtualpool
  )
AND spool_name NOT LIKE '%MXC%'
GROUP BY sap_sys_id,
  stock_id,
  form
ORDER BY form;
```

the result what i have :

```
SAP 111111  ZEBFSF_FICO1_sys     6865
SAP 222222  ZEBFSF_FICO2_sys     836
SAP 222222  ZEBFSF_FICO3_sys     83646
SAP 333333  ZEBFSF_FICO4_sys     326
SAP 222222  ZEBFSF_FICO5_sys     19
```

while the result what is desired is :

```
SAP 111111  ZEBFSF_FICO1_sys     6865
SAP 222222  ZEBFSF_FICO2_sys     836
SAP 222222  ZEBFSF_FICO3_sys     83646
SAP 333333  ZEBFSF_FICO4_sys     326
SAP 222222  ZEBFSF_FICO5_sys     19
                Total          91 692
```

any ideas how this can be done, Thanks in advance

Comment: as far as I know you can't get two different structures with the same query, that's means you can't get this structure `SAP 111111  ZEBFSF_FICO1_sys     6865` and this one `Total          91 692` in the same result, will new column with that sum will help? `SAP 111111  ZEBFSF_FICO1_sys     6865  91,692`

Comment: also it is good , and also if will write like

null,null,total,91 692

or in other column will be fine for me

Comment: you should probably use analytic functions, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174 I'll try writing an example

Comment: Magic person You are thanks alot , and also waiting for example :)

Comment: @drali, I would suggest on top to explore the [grouping functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) in oracle which makes such grouping operations flexible to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) maybe you could add a new column with the desired `sum`

```
SELECT sap_sys_id,stock_id,form, COUNT, sum(count) OVER (  ) as sum 
from (
SELECT sap_sys_id,
       stock_id,
       form,
       COUNT(*) as count
FROM tbl_doc
WHERE stock_id =
      (SELECT Q1_stock_id - 1
       FROM tbl_id_virtualpool
      )
  AND spool_name NOT LIKE '%MXC%'
GROUP BY sap_sys_id,
         stock_id,
         form
UNION ALL
SELECT sap_sys_id,
       stock_id,
       form,
       COUNT(*) as count
FROM tbl_document_log
WHERE stock_id =
      (SELECT Q2_stock_id - 1
       FROM tbl_id_virtualpool
      )
  AND spool_name NOT LIKE '%MXC%'
GROUP BY sap_sys_id,
         stock_id,
         form
ORDER BY form);
```